# Parallel Computing error using GP tool in C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#, parallel-processing

I have been using ArcGIS Geoprocessor(GP) tool whenever possible even though it is like a black box in my ArcObject development.
Most of my operations are involved with data processing, such as dataset projection, format conversion.
In order to take the advantage of my multi-core system, I decide to use parallel computing/multithreading in C# since it supports since framework 4.0:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx
So I basically modified my loop which calls GP tool.
But it works for only a few GP operations, most of others failed with error handle.
So I want to know how to resolve this issue, is there anyway I can continue to use GP in parallel computing?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What version?  What exact error do you receive?  (please update the question)

Answer (score 2):

You can't cross thread boundaries with COM objects, I'm guessing that's your issue. [Read this help topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000100000000) for some strategies to get around this.